# Dynamic graphs from frames using Networkx

Tags: networkx

I partitioned a large dataset of tweets in time-based slices and I created 1 graph per each slice.
How can I create a dynamic graph using the slices as "frames"?

I can do it using Gephi, but it is a manual process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visualize dynamic graphs is a complex topic and there's of course not a silver bullet for that.

There are different techniques out there and each library offers a different solution for such problem.

Once of the most common techniques is to combine two visualization components to show the graph in a particular "time frame" and a filter bar to slice / aggregate / navigate in time.
The filter bar an have multiple declination but one of the common pattern is a Time bar (either with line or histogram).

Where I work we recently did a webinar about this topic and offered our solution to it. Here's [the link](http://keylines.com/tag/keyline-2-0) with slides and video.
**Disclaimer**: to watch the video there's a form to fill. But the slides are publicly available.